# MySQL vs SQL differences

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am quite proficient with MySQL(7years) and I got a job interview coming up, they require SQL, from my understanding MySQL is only an interpretation of the SQL language and is most likely the same than a SQL server. Any information/tutorial or tutorial bridge you guys recommend to fill that gap in case they ask me questions on the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: Each SQL server has slight differences. Someone who says "SQL" may mean MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, etc. If they say "SQL Server" they probably mean the Microsoft variant. If I were hiring a coder, I wouldn't care as long as you understood some variant. If I was hiring a DBA, I'd care.

Comment: You need to learn some sintaxis diferences, but come to the dark side, we have cookies and analytic functions  ;)

Comment: It's an analyst position so I guess the basic queries would mainly be selects. I understand what you mean, and SQL is the father of all, going back to the roots is always a good thing lol

Comment: What's weird to me actually is that knowing 'SQL' doesn't really mean much because no one uses 'SQL' on its own.  It's on an RDBMS.  Ads usually list what sort of RDBMS you'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is an RDBMS - (Relational Database Management System).  Most of the 'sql platforms' people talk about are really one of these RDBMS's built upon the SQL rules.

Ideally, all RDBMS would implement the rules of SQL the same way, but sadly they don't.  I've worked in MySQL, SQL Server, and now I'm even doing some Postgres for Ruby on Rails development.

If you've been doing MySQL for 7 years and writing the variety of Queries for doing your Database 'crud' you should transfer to another SQL Based system pretty easily, though some (Oracle for instance) like to play with the rules than others.

Usually it's just some idiosyncratic differences in how you write the basic queries.  As long as you've written your own queries in MYSql the transit to another RDBMS should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is the common language that underlies most common Relational Database Management Systems, the big exception is MongoDB.

SQL has been around since the 70's and languages like MySQL and T-SQL aren't all that far evolved from it.  Basically, an hour of reading about the difference between MySQL and SQL will will tell you everything you need to know.

Because of this, you can confidently say at your interview that you have been using SQL for seven years!